# How $+\infty$ is identity element for min operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Studying [this case study](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/) on GPU based min reduction.

In the code it says:

```
// Infinity is the identity element for the min operation
scratch[local_index] = INFINITY;
```

What does it exactly mean?

Comment: reason for downvote?

Comment: Presumably because if you take any numerical input $n$ and ask for $\min(n,\infty)$ you get $n$.

Comment: An identity for an operation $\cdot$ is an element $e$ such that for all $a$ in your group/ring/structure $e \cdot a = a \cdot e = a$, so apply this to your example

Comment: Sorry, did not meant to approve the edit, misclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say that $0$ is the identity element for the addition operation, because $$0+a = a+0 = a$$ for any $a$. We also say that $1$ is the identity element for the multiplication operation, because $$1 \cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a$$ for all $a$. In the same way, $\infty$ is the identity element for the min operator, because $$\min(a,\infty) = \min(\infty,a) = a$$ for all $a$. In other words, all numbers are smaller than infinity.